# Error while training my dataset using dlib

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, artificial-intelligence, training-data, dlib

i just started working on face recognition using raspi 3b+ as a newbie. because of the limited computing power of pi, i want to use dlib to train a dataset that contain folders of images, each folder contain 30   images and each folder is named after a person. This is the code i used:

```py
!pip install dlib

import os
import dlib
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import joblib

# Load the Dlib face detection model
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()

# Load the Dlib face recognition model
face_rec_model_folder = '/kaggle/input/mydrivef/your_dlib_model_folder'  # Path to the folder containing the Dlib model files
face_rec_model = dlib.face_recognition_model_v1(os.path.join(face_rec_model_folder, 'dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat'))

# Step 3: Import libraries and load the dataset
data_path = '/kaggle/input/mydrivet/train'  # Path to the dataset on Kaggle's file system

images = []
labels = []

# Iterate through each folder in the dataset
for label_name in os.listdir(data_path):
    label_path = os.path.join(data_path, label_name)

    # Iterate through each image in the folder
    for img_file in os.listdir(label_path):
        img_path = os.path.join(label_path, img_file)
        img = io.imread(img_path)

        # Detect faces using Dlib face detector
        detected_faces = detector(img)

        # Ensure that at least one face is detected before computing face descriptors
        if len(detected_faces) > 0:
            # Assuming there's only one face in the image, you can use detected_faces[0] if there are multiple faces
            face = detected_faces[0]

            # Get face chip
            chip = dlib.get_face_chip(img, face, size=150, padding=0.25)

            # Compute face descriptors for the detected face
            face_descriptor = face_rec_model.compute_face_descriptor(chip)
            images.append(face_descriptor)
            labels.append(label_name)

# Step 4: Extract face embeddings
# The "images" list contains the computed face descriptors for each face in the dataset

# Step 5: Train a classifier
X = np.array(images)
y = np.array(labels)

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Train a k-Nearest Neighbors classifier
knn_classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
knn_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict on the test set
y_pred = knn_classifier.predict(X_test)

# Calculate accuracy
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
print("Accuracy:", accuracy)

# Step 6: Save the trained classifier
classifier_save_path = '/kaggle/working/trained_classifier.pkl'
joblib.dump(knn_classifier, classifier_save_path)
print("Trained classifier saved to:", classifier_save_path)
```

and i kept getting the folowing error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 43
     40 face = detected_faces[0]
     42 # Get face chip
---> 43 chip = dlib.get_face_chip(img, face, size=150, padding=0.25)
     45 # Compute face descriptors for the detected face
     46 face_descriptor = face_rec_model.compute_face_descriptor(chip)

TypeError: get_face_chip(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (img: numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8], face: _dlib_pybind11.full_object_detection, size: int = 150, padding: float = 0.25) -> numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8]
```

I was expecting the trained_classifier.pkl